# AngularJS error 400

Tags: html, angularjs, web-services

I have problem with my angular example. When try save (100-300 characters) work fine, but after enter more character (1000) in console get error 400.

In webservice (.asmx) when call stored procedure work fine regardless on character count....

Source:

```
    $scope.btnUpdate = function (id, name, desc) {
        var idVal = id;
        var supportNameVal = name;
        var supportDescriptionVal = desc;

$http.get('webservice/myService.asmx/myServiceDB?callback=?', {
            params: {
                userName: 'admin',
                procedureName: "EXECUTE wsUpdateSupport '" + idVal + "','" + supportNameVal + "','" + supportDescriptionVal + "'"
            }
        })
        .success(
          function (data) {
              $scope.message = "OK";

          })
        .error(
          function () {
              alert("error");
          }
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you are crossing the column size limit in the input  when your input is with in its size limit's then it work fine else it give error:400

Comment: I don't cross the column size!

Comment: what is the dataType of your parameter

Comment: Hassan Tariq  nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: then please check your input make sure input is correct because error 400 comes due to following reason

400 Bad Request. The server cannot or will not process the request due to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive

Comment: When use textBox (multiline) I'm save in datbase max 5048 character with space, when use angular editor can't save 2000 character (without any html character)

Comment: alert the output of angular editor and see what is the length

Comment: Then i think it must be fault in data. You are sending viia angular js

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, as it doesn't attempt to solve the OPs problem